# Renci SSH NET: Reflect width/height when resizing terminal

Tags: c#, terminal, ssh.net

I'm currently working on a terminal emulation using SSH.NET. Creating a SshClient and a ShellStream with current columns/rows work properly.

But when I change the size of the terminal dimensions (like Putty) I can't find a way to send the new colums/rows to the server.

The only way I see is to close the shellstream and create a new one. Is there a better way to send the new "layout" to the server?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

After days of investigation I ended up in implementing a new method into ShellStream.cs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a "window-change" request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columns">The terminal width in columns.</param>
    /// <param name="rows">The terminal width in rows.</param>
    /// <param name="width">The terminal height in pixels.</param>
    /// <param name="height">The terminal height in pixels.</param>
    public void SendWindowChangeRequest(uint columns, uint rows, uint width, uint height)
    {
        if (_channel == null)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("ShellStream");
        }
        _channel.SendWindowChangeRequest(columns, rows, width, height);
    }
```

That solved the problem. Now I can call "SendWindowChangeRequest(...)" and the server-side shell window is up to date :-)

Not sure, why this feature is missing in Renci's implementation. Maybe there is still another way...

Comment: I ended up getting the `_channel` private by reflection and then invoking the method on it.